# PropTypes not showing any warnings for invalid types - React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am implementing PropTypes for the first time but it's not validating props as expected. There are no warnings when there is mismatched data types or if there's no data passed, and just displays text as is. Below is the code for the components:

The Component:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  /** some other code **/

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.appContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.count}>{this.state.count}</ Text>
        <Text>{this.props.num}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

Counter.propTypes = {
  num: PropTypes.number.isRequired
}
```

Here's where the component is being used:

```
<View style={styles.appContainer}>
  <Button title="toggle" onPress={this.toggleCounter}/>
  <Counter num={"hi"}/>
</View>
```

Comment: PropTypes working only in dev mode. Where are you testing? In console no warnings?

Comment: @s0xzwasd I am using snack.expo.io for development